# Opening port on classic azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I have created inbound and outbound rule on the virtual machine to allow any connection to port 5100 over tcp. 
I have created an endpoint in the new Azure portal for TCP and public/private port 5100, but for some reason I can't comprehend I still can't connect.

I tried to turn off the firewall on the virtual machine, but still I can't connect to the virtual machine.

I have previously done this for port 80 with no problems. Does anyone know if Microsoft have changed anything that affects the classic vm's and endpoint configuration?

Comment: Does this VM create in classic VM? Or create via new portal?

Comment: This is an older vm created in classic

Comment: Add port 80 via new portal or classic portal?

Comment: that was probably done using the old portal since the vm was created a while back

Comment: can you access the service in that VM with 127.0.0.1:5100? or does that service running?

Comment: Yes it works when accessed locally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156636/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-jonas-roineslien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add endpoints via New Azure portal in this way:

[image]

We should make sure the update endpoint completed.

Hope this helps:)